# My mobile media query is overriding my desktop Style. How do I stop this?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following media queries throughout my stylesheet:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024x), only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation : portrait)

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px), only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation : portrait)
```

For some reason the 320px wide media query is overwriting my normal styles for the desktop version. What am I doing wrong, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the first media query. You're missing the 'p' from 'px'.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation : portrait) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px), only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation : portrait) {

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4jqztmd/3/show

However, I recommend not targeting specific device sizes. Device's are always changing - we can define media queries depending on the *content*, rather than specific device sizes. An interface should look good on any size.

Read more about this [here](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/#content)

So, maybe you could simplify your media queries, and only target specifics if you need to.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

Also it's good practice to have a mobile first approach. Instead of using `max-width`, you can use `min-width`. Your 'normal' styles (without breakpoints), would be mobile styles.

Comment: Targeting device orientation can be useful though. I wouldn't leave that out completely.

Comment: Cheers, turns out I had one too many closing brackets for the Mobile query, however I will take on board your advice.